# textFieldShouldReturn func not working on scrollView

Tags: swift, xcode10, touchesbegan

How could i make the text disappeared when the user tap the screen when UIscrollview is active

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
```

I'm using the typical func for get and dismiss the keyboard

I try to

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        UIScrollView.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: UIScrollView.endEditing(true) this is not true. Delete 'UIScrollView' and type the scrollview name

Comment: didn't work 
    @IBOutlet var elskroll: UIScrollView!
     elskroll.endEditing(true)
i even try to outlet the ImageView and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ViewDidLoad

```
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.touch))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        elskrolll.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

elskroll must be your UIScrollView name:

outside the ViewDidLoad

```
@objc func touch() {
        //print("Touches")
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This in viewdidLoad ()

```
let scrollViewTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.scrollViewTapped))
        scrollViewTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        scroll_view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollViewTap)
```

and This in class

```
@objc func scrollViewTapped() {
        scroll_view.endEditing(true) 
        self.view.endEditing(true) // anyone
    }
```